# Python - Inserting and Updating python dict simultaneously

Tags: python

so I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```py
[{
  'field': {
    'data': 'F1'
  },
  'value': F1Value1,
  'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0)
}, {
  'field': {
    'data': 'F2'
  },
  'value': F2Value1,
  'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0)
}, {
  'field': {
    'data': 'F2'
  },
  'value': F2Value2,
  'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0)
}]
```

And I want an output that looks like this:

```py
[
  {
    'F1': [
      {
        'value': F1Value1,
        'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'F2': [
      {
        'value': F2Value1,
        'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0)
      },
      {
        'value': F2Value2,
        'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0)
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

That is, I want every `field.data` to be the key and have it append the `value` and `date` if it belongs to the same field.

**Note:** I want to do this WITHOUT using a for loop (apart from the loop to iterate through the list). I want to use python dict functions like `update()` and `append()` etc.

Any optimized solutions would be really helpful.

Comment: `append` is not a dict function...

Comment: @Netwave Please go through the example. I was talking about https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `iterate` through the `list` of `dict`s and use `defaultdict` from `collections` to add the items with a unique key,

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>>
>>> for items in x:
...   d[items['field']['data']].append({
...     'value': items['value'],
...     'date': items['date']
...   })
...
>>> 
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0),
  'field': {'data': 'F1'},
  'value': 'F1Value1'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0),
  'field': {'data': 'F2'},
  'value': 'F2Value1'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0),
  'field': {'data': 'F2'},
  'value': 'F2Value2'}]
>>>
>>> pprint.pprint(list(d.items()))
[('F1', [{'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'value': 'F1Value1'}]),
 ('F2',
  [{'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0), 'value': 'F2Value1'},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0), 'value': 'F2Value2'}])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

result = [{key: [{k: v for k, v in element.items() if k != 'field'} 
                 for element in group]} 
          for key, group in groupby(data, lambda element: element['field']['data'])]

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'F1': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0), 'value': 'F1Value1'}]},
 {'F2': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 0, 0), 'value': 'F2Value1'},
         {'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 7, 0, 0), 'value': 'F2Value2'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only using dict, list, and set:

```
[ 
  { 
    field_data :
      [ 
        { k:v for k, v in thing.items() if k != 'field' }
        for thing in things if thing['field']['data'] == field_data 
      ]
    for field_data in set(thing['field']['data'] for thing in things)
  } 
]
```